# How can I restart or reset the K3s cluster pods

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have a k3s (`v1.21.1`+`k3s1`) cluster with following pods:

```
kube-system   pod/calico-node-xxxx                          
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-xxxxxx   
kube-system   pod/metrics-server-xxxxx
kube-system   pod/local-path-provisioner-xxxxx
kube-system   pod/coredns-xxxxx
```

How can I restart (stop and start the pods again) the pods either with command (`kubectl` maybe) or any script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubernetes doesn't support stopping/pausing the current state of Pods. However, you can perform a rollout restart of the `Deployment`/`DaemonSet` with the `kubectl rollout restart` command (see: [the Kubectl Reference Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-restart-em-)).

To restart all `Deployments` and `DaemonSets` in the `kube-system` namespace, you can use the following command:

```
# kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart daemonsets,deployments
daemonset.apps/calico-node restarted
deployment.apps/local-path-provisioner restarted
deployment.apps/coredns restarted
deployment.apps/metrics-server restarted
deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers restarted
```

As you probably noticed from the output above, the `calico-node` is a `DaemonSet` and rest of the Pods are managed by `Deployments`.

If you want, you can restart specific `Deployment`/`Daemonset`:

```
# kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart deployment metrics-server
deployment.apps/metrics-server restarted
# kubectl get pod -n kube-system | grep metrics-server
metrics-server-6bd8786b6c-74qlt            1/1     Running       0          2s
metrics-server-647d5b4475-ch9zj            1/1     Terminating   0          28s
```

Comment: Hello @solveit. Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor : Yes it worked for me. Thanks a lot