# How can I restart or reset the custom namespace pods

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have a k3s cluster with `kube-system` pods and my application's (`xyz-system` namespace) pods:

```
kube-system   pod/calico-node-xxxx                          
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-xxxxxx   
kube-system   pod/metrics-server-xxxxx
kube-system   pod/local-path-provisioner-xxxxx
kube-system   pod/coredns-xxxxx
xyz-system    pod/my-app
xyz-system    pod/my-app-mqtt
```

I want to reset/restart all of these pods (kube-system + xyz-system) in one command (or it can be two commands for two namespace but without deployment name) without giving deployment names because in future I can have more deployments created, so it will be difficult to provide many deployment names manually.

**Debugging:**
With command  `kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart daemonsets,deployments` as mentioned in [link](https://serverfault.com/a/1074054/692191) I am able to restart the `kube-system` pods. But when I modify this command with `xyz-namespace` : `kubectl -n xyz-system rollout restart deployments` the respective pods are not restarting when I monitor `watch kubectl get all -A` they remain as it is in Running state.

Can someone let me know how to achieve this ?

Comment: But why would you want to restart them? it is against the principles k8s is built for

Comment: @Jonas: I want to understand more about what you said that "its against the principle....". Can you provide any k3s/k8s official doc from where it can be evident ?

Comment: Pods are disposable, e.g. immutable architecture - you don't mutate, but throw away (delete) and instead create new pods. It is not intended to change anything about a Pod. See e.g. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#working-with-pods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two commands:

```
kubectl delete pod -n kube-system --all
kubectl delete pod -n xyz-system --all
```

In "one":

```
kubectl get pods -A | awk 'NR>1{print $1" "$2}' \
    | while read ns pod; do \
        kubectl delete -n $ns pod $pod; done
```

Or:

```
kubectl get ns | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' \
    | while read ns; do \
         kubectl delete pod -n $ns --all; done
```

Though I second @jonas comment: sounds like a weird question, with no real-life use cases that I know of.

Comment: Or you could issue `kubectl delete pod --all --all-namespaces`, but this will restart (or delete if not in deployment) absolutely everything.